# Jquery ajax async "True" is not working sequentialy

Tags: jquery

```
function loadDropDown(targetControl, url, type,data)
{
 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            async:true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
             "do some thing."
            },error: function (data) {
             "do some thing."
            }
      });
}
```

and Call

```
loadDropDown ('#CountryId', '/Common/Country','GET');
loadDropDown('#StateId', '/Common/State','GET',data);
loadDropDown('#District', '/Common/District','GET',data);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's going on, what's the expected behaviour and what's happening differently?

Comment: `async` means that it will run immediately instead of waiting for the previous call to return. So, they can end up returning in a different order than being called. If you want them to run sequentially you should set `async: false`

Comment: `"do some thing."` is only valid javascript in that it defines an anonymous literal string.  Your code does nothing.  It's difficult to even tell what your intention is, except perhaps that you want to provide new `option` elements for some `select`

Answer (score 3):

`loadDropDown` should return a promise, you can call the next function when the promise is resolved.

```
function loadDropDown(targetControl, url, type,data)
{
    return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            async:true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
             "do some thing."
            },error: function (data) {
             "do some thing."
            }
      });
}

loadDropDown('#CountryId', '/Common/Country','GET').then(function() {
    loadDropDown('#StateId', '/Common/State','GET',data).then(function() {
        loadDropDown('#District', '/Common/District','GET',data);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`async: true` is the default, and means to happen in any order in the background.

You want `async: false` for your code to be synchronous, based on the question in your title.

If this isn't accurate, please fill us in with more details.

As you want synchronous behaviour whilst being asynchronous, try calling the second load() function within the success callback of the first one. It will need some careful coding to avoid an infinite loop.

Just a sec, I'll update my answer with an example.

Edit: pipped to the punch by @Barmar, try their solution!

Comment: yap, is there any way it will done in async :true mode ?

Comment: Yep by judicious use of callbacks, I've updated my answer with explanation and will update with code now too